# When should i go for "spring.net" in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spring.net

When should i go for spring.net framework in asp.net mvc web application? A simple example which could explain its usage in a web application... Any suggestion..

**EDIT:**

Why spring is used? What is the use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.springframework.net contains lots of different modules, so it might be difficult to answer your question.

But [this page](http://www.springframework.net/overview.html) gives a nice overview of what's contained in spring.net framework and [this page](http://www.springframework.net/examples.html) lists some examples/tutorials.

**Update**: There are really a lot of different reasons why to use spring.net (have a look at the tutorials), e.g: dependency injection, simplifying data access, internationalization support, etc., etc.